# Create mongoose schema methods using TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I try to create method hashPassword for user schema.

```
schema.method("hashPassword", function (): void {
  const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
  const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, salt);

  this.password = hash;
});
```

And get an error `Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Document<any>'.` on password

Here is my file

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

/**
 * This interface should be the same as JWTPayload declared in types/global.d.ts file
 */
export interface IUser extends Document {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  confirmed: boolean;
  hashPassword: () => void;
  checkPassword: (password: string) => boolean;
}

// User schema
const schema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    confirmed: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

schema.method("hashPassword", function (): void {
  const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
  const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, salt);

  this.password = hash;
});

// User model
export const User = mongoose.model<IUser>("User", schema, "users");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the point where you define the method, the `schema` object doesn't know that it is the `Schema` for an `IUser` and not just any `Document`.  You need to set the generic type for the `Schema` when you create it: `new Schema<IUser>( ... )`.

Comment: Much simpler than other answers.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by one of the collaborators of mongoose, we can use the below way for creating instance methods:

```
const schema = new Schema<ITestModel, Model<ITestModel, {}, InstanceMethods>> // InstanceMethods would be the interface on which we would define the methods

schema.methods.methodName = function() {}

const Model = model<ITestModel, Model<ITestModel, {}, InstanceMethods>>("testModel", ModelSchema)

const modelInstance = new Model();
modelInstance.methodName() // works
```

link: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10358#issuecomment-861779692

Answer (score 5):

This makes is Clear Enough

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document, Model } from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

interface IUser {
    username: string;
    hashedPassword: string;
}

interface IUserDocument extends IUser, Document {
    setPassword: (password: string) => Promise<void>;
    checkPassword: (password: string) => Promise<boolean>;
}

interface IUserModel extends Model<IUserDocument> {
    findByUsername: (username: string) => Promise<IUserDocument>;
}

const UserSchema: Schema<IUserDocument> = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    hashedPassword: { type: String, required: true },
});

UserSchema.methods.setPassword = async function (password: string) {
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    this.hashedPassword = hash;
};

UserSchema.methods.checkPassword = async function (password: string) {
    const result = await bcrypt.compare(password, this.hashedPassword);
    return result;
};

UserSchema.statics.findByUsername = function (username: string) {
    return this.findOne({ username });
};

const User = mongoose.model<IUserDocument, IUserModel>("User", UserSchema);
export default User;
```

Comment: Great example, makes everything nice and clear.

Comment: Make sure not to use arrow functions when defining methods! I usually write arrow functions everywhere, but I forgot that "this" is not available in arrow functions. Took me couple of minutes to remember that.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare an interface that extends Model like so:

```
    interface IUser {...}
    interface IUserInstanceCreation extends Model<IUser> {}
```

then declare your schema;

```
    const userSchema = new Schema<IUser, IUserInstanceCreation, IUser>({...})
```

This would as well ensure that the Schema follows the attributes in IUser.

Comment: I already figured it out but thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Solution to avoid having to redefine types that are already in the schema

```
import { Schema, model, InferSchemaType } from "mongoose"
import bcrypt from "bcrypt"

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: String,
})

userSchema.methods.verifyPassword = async function(password: string){
    return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password)
}

declare interface IUser extends InferSchemaType<typeof userSchema> {
    verifyPassword(password: string): boolean
}

export const UserModel = model<IUser>("Users", userSchema)
```